# What does the highest $10$% signify when talking about normal distribution curves?

Tags: statistics

Based on the model $N(\mu = 1152, \sigma^2 = 84)$ what are the cutoff values for the highest $10\%$? What does the highest $10\%$ mean? Also, what are cutoff values? Like $z$-score?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Let's say the random variable associated to the model is $X$. Then the "cutoff value" for the highest $10\%$ is actually the value $x$ which $P(X > x) = 10\% \Leftrightarrow P(X \leq x) = 90\%$. Only $10\%$ equals/higher than this particular cutoff value. If you concern about the curve of the distribution, $10\%$ area under the curve is on the **right**-hand side of the "cutoff value". (On the other hand for the lowest $10\%$ is when $P(X \leq x) = 10\%$.)

So indeed you can use the concept of $z$-score to get that value of $x$:
$$ P(X \leq x) = P\left(Z = \dfrac{X - 1152}{\sqrt{84}} \leq \dfrac{x - 1152}{\sqrt{84}} \right) = 0.9 $$

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{x - 1152}{\sqrt{84}} = 1.28155 \Rightarrow x = \cdots$$

Also try [this Z-score calculator](https://www.calculator.net/z-score-calculator.html) in case you want to test for other cutoff values, and [Online Stat Book](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/normal_distribution/normal_distribution.html) for more in-depth understanding about Normal distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Comment in 'Answer' format for legibility: In R statistical software `dnorm` denotes a normal PDF, `pnorm` denotes a normal CDF, and `qnorm` denotes a normal quantile function (inverse CDF).

if $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1152,\sigma=\sqrt{84}),$ then in R, code `qnorm(.9,1152, sqrt(84))`returns quantile 90, which is 1163.746.

```
qnorm(.9, 1152, sqrt(84))
[1] 1163.746
```

Then using the CDF, code `pnorm(1163.746,1152,sqrt(84))` returns 0.9000074, confirming that 90% of this normal population lies below 1163.746.

```
pnorm(1163.746, 1152, sqrt(84))
[1] 0.9000074

curve(dnorm(x, 1152, sqrt(84)), 1100, 1200, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="")
  abline(h = 0, col="green2")
  abline(v = 1163.746, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Note:* R is excellent free software with versions for Windows, Mac, and Unix, available from `r-project.org`. It is worth having, if only for its probability functions for most of the often-used distributions: normal, uniform, exponential, chi-squared, gamma, beta; binomial, Poisson, and so on.